# how can i stream microphone input from a windows 10 machine to ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows, bluetooth, ubuntu-18.04, audio-streaming, microphone

i am looking for a way to stream audio input(+output) from a windows 10 machine into my Linux Ubuntu 20.04.2LTS machine.
I have already tried connecting them via Bluetooth but i can only transfer Audio output and not input.
I can hear from the Linux but can't speak as my windows is showing the Ubuntu under output devices and not input devices

solution via Bluetooth is preferred but WiFi will also be accepted.

Comment: Are you talking about a virtual machine?

Comment: no, i am talking about two different computers which are running in parallel one next to each other; so i want to be able to hear and speak from/to both computer from one set of headphones.

Comment: The best solution is to buy a usb splitter or some sort of cable that allows you to do so.

Comment: i am looking for software solution, since both computers have Bluetooth and WiFi- there's no reason not to use one in order to transmit audio.